# PDI - Block this step until steps finished not working

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

Why my `Block this step until steps finished` not work? I should wait all my insert step before run rest of them. Any suggestion?

[image: My Transformation Looks like]
[image: Block this steps until finished]

Comment: What do you mean "Don't finish" '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are possibly confusing blocking the data flow and finishing the connection. See [there](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/145726-quot-Block-this-step-until-steps-finish-quot-doesn-t-work/).

As far as I can understand by you questions since 3 month, you should really have a look [here](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Beginners+FAQ#BeginnersFAQ-What'sthedifferencebetweentransformationsandjobs?) and [there](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Database+transactions+in+jobs+and+transformations).

And try to move to writing Jobs (kjb) to orchestrate your transformations (ktr).

Answer (score 2):

All table input step will run parallelly when you execute the transformation.

If you want to stop table execution then I suggest adding one constant (i.e 1) before block until step and in the table input step you can add one condition like **where 1 = ?** with option enabling  and **execute for each row**

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to be working mate, no matter what block step we have table input works concurrently it doesn't wait at all. I think it's better to have it as a separate transformation whatever we try to achieve, this is a pain limiting our design pattern.